# SVN - update not working for new checkouts in cron.daily script

Tags: svn

I have multiple checkouts (11 in total) on a NAS server that I have a cron.daily script to update the checkouts (from repositories on another server). I set this up recently, but for the last three checkouts I setup, the update command doesn't return any output when the script runs daily.

I did capture the stderr output from one of the failing updates, and the return code was 1,which I believe to be a standard 'something was wrong' response in a script. What I don't understand is, if I log in as root, copy the run-parts command from crontab and run it, then ALL the updates work as expected?

The script will email me with stdout of each update. An extract is shown below which shows Updating 'SVN-Documents' is not working (no output), but the others do work.

```
Updating 'SVN-COAA':
At revision 2558.

Updating 'SVN-Credentials':
At revision 3.

Updating 'SVN-Development':
At revision 2573.

Updating 'SVN-Documents':

Updating 'SVN-Downloads':
At revision 167.
```

I created the checkouts logged in as 'root' using:

```
svn checkout svn://192.168.1.19/Documents SVN-Documents
```

I created another script to capture stderr on one of the failing checkouts to try to figure out whats going wrong

```
#!/bin/bash

. /frontview/bin/functions
get_language_strings

cd /c

resultA="$(svn update SVN-Documents1)"
exitA=$?

mesg="$resultA\r\nExit  Code $exitA\r\n\n"

subject="ReadyNAS Duo SVN Documents Update "$(date +%T)
send_email_alert "$subject" "$mesg" "$EMAIL"

##save the message to status log
log_status "$subject" 0
```

The result of this when run by cron.daily is just the following

```
Updating 'SVN-Documents1':
Exit  Code 1
```

but when I run this script logged in as root I get

```
Updating 'SVN-Documents1':
At revision 2944.
Exit  Code 0
```

**So - I think my REAL question is - How can I capture more information on whats happening when cron.daily runs?**

I've been using TortoiseSVN on Windows machines for many years, but I don't have much experience using the terminal in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

these repositories might be configured differently; not having user `root` added.

besides, [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) expects a path an not a repository name.

Comment: I did think it might be a user issue, but as it works when I log in as root, and run an update separately, and also works when I run the script as rot user, then in my limited knowledge, I can't see lack of root user being an issue - welcome to be proved wrong though - the actual repositories are public access (being on my private network), and the checkouts I'm trying to update were done from root login. I would have expected some error on stdout from SVN if it was lack of permissions however

Answer (score 0):

ok - so found the solution

Added stderr to stdout using the following

```
svn update $1 2>&1
```

Which showed the command was failing translating UTF-8 into native language

Found the bash script was using posix, when root login uses utf-8

added the following to the bash script to fix it

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
```

Everything works fine now